# Ruby Watir Gem, Timing Out on Form Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir

I'm practicing webscraping using Watir, Mechanize and Nokigiri gems.

I'm running into an issue with my Watir script. My plan is to get a list of prices from flights via http://tripadvisor.com/. When I run the script, the Chrome browser opens as it should, the script proceeds to fill out the first parts of the form, origin and destination and then it halts. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
This code has slept for the duration of the default timeout waiting for an Element to be present. If the test is still passing, consider using Element#exists? instead of rescuing UnknownObjectException
/home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:515:in `rescue in wait_for_present': element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for true condition on #<Watir::Input: located: true; {:name=>"rt_leaveday", :tag_name=>"input"}> (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
    from /home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:505:in `wait_for_present'
    from /home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:522:in `wait_for_enabled'
    from /home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:534:in `wait_for_writable'
    from /home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:639:in `element_call'
    from /home/jaffejoe/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.2.0/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:303:in `send_keys'
    from watir_test.rb:8:in `<main>' </
```

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto('https://tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome')
browser.input(name: 'orig').send_keys('Boston, MA - Logan International Airport (BOS)')
browser.input(name: 'dest').send_keys('Milan, Italy - All Airports (MIL)')
browser.input(name: 'rt_leaveday').send_keys('1')
browser.input(name: 'rt_leavemonth').send_keys('06/2017')
browser.input(name: 'retday').send_keys('30')
browser.input(name: 'leavemonth').send_keys('06/2017')
browser.input(value: 'Search Flights').click
puts browser.url
browser.quit
```

Comment: is the element present?

Comment: I get a true when i do this: puts browser.input(name: 'rt_leaveday').exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't set value on the `rt_leaveday` or `rt_leavemonth` because they are hidden inputs. But you can execute a script to click on `dateselector`:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto('https://tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome')
browser.text_field(name: 'orig').set('Boston, MA - Logan International Airport (BOS)')
browser.text_field(name: 'dest').set('Milan, Italy - All Airports (MIL)')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".in_date").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_28").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".out_date").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_2").click()')
browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").fire_event :click
puts browser.url
browser.quit
=> https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsSearchResults-g187849-a_airport0.BOS-a_airport1.MIL-a_cos.0-a_date0.20170328-a_date1.20170402-a_nearby0.no-a_nearby1.no-a_nonstop.no-a_pax0.a-a_travelers.1-Milan_Lombardy.html
```

Comment: At first I was thinking that it was something up with tripadvisor, so i was trying something on kayak and was running into the same problem. That's when I realize that they both were using jquery datepicker. I was then trying to search how to get Watir to work with datepicker. Thanks man, you got me pointed towards the right way in solving my problem

Comment: No worries it was a fun problem to fix :)

Comment: Hey another quick question. I'm playing around with the script again this morning and I'm just not realizing I'm getting a different results for the puts browser.url. Mine is spitting out: https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome