# Ruby Waitir Gem, getting unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler, watir, watir-webdriver

2 weeks ago I put up post about my watir script timing out on me, I was able to get a solution but I realized to late the results I was getting was different than the person that helped me out. Here is the original post: [Ruby Watir Gem, Timing Out on Form Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797887/ruby-watir-gem-timing-out-on-form-input)

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto('https://tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome')
browser.text_field(name: 'orig').set('Boston, MA - Logan International Airport (BOS)')
browser.text_field(name: 'dest').set('Milan, Italy - All Airports (MIL)')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".in_date").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_28").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".out_date").click()')
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_2").click()')
browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").fire_event :click
puts browser.url
browser.quit
```

The person who wrote that code got this as a result:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsSearchResults-g187849-a_airport0.BOS-a_airport1.MIL-a_cos.0-a_date0.20170328-a_date1.20170402-a_nearby0.no-a_nearby1.no-a_nonstop.no-a_pax0.a-a_travelers.1-Milan_Lombardy.html

I have the same code in my script and for some reason I'm only getting:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome

It seems as though the button click isn't happening for me, not sure. I tried both chrome and firefox.

Comment: What version of Chrome, Chromedriver, Selenium-Webdriver and Watir are you using? I am wondering if there is a difference to explain why we are seeing different results for the same code.

Comment: Chrome: 57.0.2987.98, Chromedriver: 2.28.455506, Selenium-Webdriver: 3.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your click actually opens another two window and also the time you are clicking it's not exactly receiving the click, Please use this code, it will work for you and you will be left with your expected window

```
require 'watir'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(marionette: false)

driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps, profile: "default"

b=Watir::Browser.new driver


b.goto('https://tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome')
b.text_field(name: 'orig').set('Boston, MA - Logan International Airport (BOS)')
b.text_field(name: 'dest').set('Milan, Italy - All Airports (MIL)')
b.execute_script('document.querySelector(".in_date").click()')
b.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_28").click()')
b.execute_script('document.querySelector(".out_date").click()')
b.execute_script('document.querySelector(".day_2").click()')
begin
b.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='CHECK_FARES_BUTTON']").click
end until b.windows.count>1

b.windows[0].close
b.windows[1].close

puts b.url
b.quit
```

Comment: This gets me where i want to go thanks. But I'm confused on how it works, you want to explain the first few lines with caps, and driver? Also the difference b.element(xpath: ".//*[@id='CHECK_FARES_BUTTON']").click and browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").fire_event :click

Comment: Caps I have included to not to invoke Geckodriver instead to use the legacy firefox driver, but this is not important, you can explore later. And element(xpath,'') and span(:id,'') doesn't differ, it works in the same way, Both works, Just try using span, it will work. The point to be noted here is, your button is not receiving the click properly when you excute the click statement, So to make sure your button receives the click properly, I wrote this condition `b.windows.count>1` and then I closed the window which you don't want so b variable automatically connected toyourwindow to print url.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I changed `.fire_event :click` to `.click`.

Then there was an error that appeared.

> Please enter a valid airport code or city.

Secondly, I tried this:

```
browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").click
browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").click
puts browser.url
```

And it redirected me to: 
`https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsSearchResults-g187849-a_airport0.BOS-a_airport1.MIL-a_cos.0-a_date0.20170401-a_date1.20170402-a_nearby0.no-a_nearby1.no-a_nonstop.no-a_pax0.a-a_travelers.1-Milan_Lombardy.html`

To be honest I have no idea why it does not register the input during the first click...

I am using chrome.

Comment: Just tried it, and I'm still getting: https://www.tripadvisor.com/CheapFlightsHome On Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters, this is weird :/

Comment: I am also using Ubuntu 16.04. Did you try double click for sure? Did the invalid message appear/Was there click event at all?

Comment: Yes I tried the double click, I didn't get an error message. I dont think think I'm getting a click event at all. The browser closes automatically after filling in the date, even after removing the browser.quit line.

Comment: What if you use `browser.execute_script('document.getElementById("CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").click()')`?

Comment: Error: `assert_ok': unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of null (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Comment: Looks like there is no element with that id. Can you show output of `puts browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").inspect`? Also try checking that button or rather span in the console.

Comment: Not locating the span: #<Watir::Span: located: false; {:id=>"CHECK_FARES_BUTTON", :tag_name=>"span"}>

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. Could you use `browser.span(id: "CHECK_FARES_BUTTON").flash` It should change the color of that span to red for a sec.

Comment: Yes it did flash red for a split second.